# Azure DevOps - Wiki link in overview - how to forward to home page instead of new page form

Tags: azure-devops

When I go to Overview->Wiki I see a new doc form:
[image]

When I remove selected part of the URL (see selected URL on 1st photo) then I'm forwarded to home page:
[image]

How to set 2nd page as initial?

Comment: Hi Piotrek, what is the latest status of this issue? Has my post helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my test, I was able to reproduce your issue.

In my wiki, usually I will be navigated to the Project Wiki, and when I enter the code wikis below, especially those that have nothing inside, like my "testwiki" below. I would also be trapped in the same loop as yours until I edit the url with "dev.azure.com/abc/xyz/_wiki/wikis/projectname.wiki".
[image]

So I tried the [rest api to delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) the empty wiki, and I am able to jump out of the loop by myself.

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}?api-version=7.0
```

[image]